I definitely did something wrong, but dont know what

Just got done with my LEGO BMW M 1000 RR (42130). As most of the set is built on the stand I never came across this issue until I tried using that wheel jack thingy. The entire front side moves when I put weight on the bike.

You mean the steering rotates from neutral position to one side?
